# Integral 1/x-1 convergent?

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

$$\int\limits_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{x-1}$$

I have determined the corresponding stem function by means of substitution:
$$ F(x)= ln(|x-1|)+C$$

I know that this integral diverges, but how do I show this formally now?

Comment: Compute (or try to compute) $~\displaystyle \lim_{a \to 1+} \int_a^2 \frac{1}{x-1} ~dx.$

Comment: One way is to find $\int_a^2dx/(x-1)$ as a function of $a$, then show it is unbounded on $(1,2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the primitive function you found we can apply the FTC to get that

$$\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-1}=\lim_{a\downarrow1}\int_a^2\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x-1}=\lim_{a\downarrow1}\biggl[\ln\lvert x-1\rvert\biggr]_a^2=\lim_{a\downarrow1}\bigl(\ln1-\ln (a-1)\bigr)=\infty,$$

since $\ln x\to-\infty$ as $x\downarrow0$ (the limit comes from the integral being generalized at $1$).